# Ordering of query array parameters with Jersey

Tags: java, arrays, rest, jersey

I am writing REST service, which have array query parameter. RESTful Web Services framework is Jersey 2.23 (but I can upgrade if necessary). URL looks like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/restservices/data?sort=id&sort=name&sort=description
```

Here "sort" is array query parameter. The ordering of the parameter values is important because they are used for sorting. This parameter is defined in code like this:

```
@QueryParam("sort") final List<String> sort
```

The code works as expected, but I am not sure if the ordering is always preserved.

Can you please help me to understand is it OK to rely on the ordering of the values, or there can be situations when ordering in the `sort` Java list is different from the ordering in URL?

Comment: No, you can not rely on the order being preserved as the order does not matter by definition ("The order of the queries doesn't matter", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) so if the order is important you have to e.g. expect a single "sort" parameter with comma separation or else. Edit: Not being said that some frameworks might keep the order totally correct, but experience shows that when e.g. a proxy is involved that takes definitions too seriously, behaviour might change.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is ok. As List is ordered collection.  By the way, you can test this easily as well. Just tried several times.

MKYONG offer a very good [example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/).